# Jersey Test Framework issue on Netbeans with Maven and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, netbeans-7

I'm using Jersey Test Framework in NetBeans 7.1 where my JSON webservices are hosted on the included Tomcat instance :8084.

I'm getting the following exception when trying to run any tests:

```
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/internet/ParseException
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Maven fragment:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

As this adds the missing concrete implementations.